# Appropriate action to take once I've run 30 regressions with same IVs but tweaked DV

Tags: least-squares, negative-binomial-distribution, false-discovery-rate

I run 30 OLS and GLM regressions using the same 9 IV/variables/features, but each with a slightly tweaked DV/target/label. More or less the same same variables are significant each time, but DV-tweaks produces interesting variations regarding which IVs are significant and which are not. I have captured it all in a table, and feel the IVs that keep surfacing time after time (say 25 out of 30 regressions) are better predictors that those that come up only once or twice (as significant). However, I feel I might be accused of fooling myself by running so many regressions. Should I be using to sort of correction or penalty? How is this done?

Note 1: I'm teaching myself statistics, and have rather a few gaps in my knowledge.

Note 2: I use OLS for all the versions of the Target which are continuous. I use a "Negative Binomial" for the others, because it is count data, and overdispersed.

Note 3: I look at the number of protests in municipalities (i.e. count), but then also at protests/capita ; protests*size of protests / capita ; violent protests only / capita (all per municipality), and so on.

Note 4: When the IVs are significant, they are properly so - p values less than 0.001.

Is this unease of mine something to do with "false discovery rates"? Am I way off course?

Speak, oh wise ones.

Answer (score 0):

**State of play**: There seems to be all sorts of corrections for multiple testing for *some* significance - especially in medical trails, where the efficacy of a drug is tested in slightly different doses, say. Such multiple tests naturally suffer, statistically, in that the more one tests, the more one is confronted by the likelihood of getting false positives. Crudely put - if you test a ineffectual drug enough times, you may find a case where the evidence seems to suggest efficacy.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20589856

To correct for these troubles, there is a whole family of adjustments and penalties - Bonferroni and Benjamini-Hochberg are two of several methods that has come up in my reading over the past week.

Still, until someone can tell me otherwise, I suspect I should maintain that, if one measures Y as a function of A, B, D and C, where one subjects Y to a series of tweaks, running the regression anew every time (and never changing A, B C and D), that, as long as one reports the findings from ALL the regressions, one is operating above board. Hence, if A and B presents p-values of less than 0.001 in 90% of the regressions (with coefficients in the same direction), I should be ok to say that A and B seems to matter, regardless of how one twiddles Y.

My intuition is that this is a precarious move, but I don't have the statistical wherewithal to express the problem more eloquently.

Comment: Please add this to your question, rather than posting it as an answer

Comment: Before I can give a good answer, I'd need to know why you are doing all this tweaking and what the tweaking consisted of.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks! This is possibly too specific for the question, but if it helps, by all means. I am looking at several theories (from different social scientists) about why people in a certain country protest (so much). Community protests, mostly. They present arguments like poverty, inequality, poor services and landlessness. My response is to consider the data - using a dataset that assigns over a hundred thousand protests to municipalities, I can consider the actual conditions in the municipalities to see if they theories hold water.

Comment: However, the target is, to me, uncertain. It could be protests per municipality, but it could also be protests per capita in each municipality. But since urban protest events and much larger than rural ones, I also consider the count times the average size of protests (effectively person-days of protests), per capita, per municipality. This means that the folks whom I effectively "test" cannot accuse me of cherry picking a DV in order to discredit their theory. Does this clarify? Again, thanks.

Comment: I'd say you are then testing fairly different things. You should probably decide on one, based on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe, but I think this misses the point of my question. Besides, my results look very similar, no matter how I tweak the DV. All I want to know is whether there is a standard procedure I should apply before reporting the various findings. If not, then my answer, above, might stand, since it suggests that no, there is no action to be taken. But obviously, if there is a way to deal with this sort of challenge, my answer is no answer at all.